# Arch linux graphics problems

Tags: linux, graphics-card, arch-linux

I've been trying to install various versions of arch (Manjaro, architect...). All goes well except for a graphics problem. I've tried updating drivers, changing window managers...to no avail. Actually the only linux distro to work right is ubuntu, even fedora didn't work right. 
Here is what I'm seeing: [image: graphics problems]

text on windows is all screwed up, but text on websites for example looks fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: I am using intel graphics with i915 driver in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out deleting the video-intel driver with "sudo mhwd -r video-intel" solved the problem. My system still shows that it is running the video-intel driver, but I'm not too worried as long as it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

For Arch, it may be the default acceleration method used by your intel driver (should be something like /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf).

The default is "sna". You might want to try changing it to "uxa" by adding the following line to the above configuration file:
Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"

Source (a very useful page generally):
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#SNA_issues